# Category column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was just wondering if this is the most efficient way to use categories:

```
---------------------------------
| ID   | ITEM      | CATEGORY   |
---------------------------------
| 1    | COOKIES   | FOOD       |
| 2    | CAKE      | FOOD       |
| 3    | WATER     | DRINK      |
| 4    | PEANUTS   | FOOD       |
| 5    | PEPSI     | DRINK      |
---------------------------------
 ↑ int  ↑ text      ↑ text        <- [ type of column ]
```

Then my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE category='FOOD';
```

Comment: I want to know if thats the most efficient way to structure a category column. Ive seen some databases with numbers to represent the category names. Is that more efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think if you change a little bit, for example, category column in categories ID,

```
`---------------------------------
| ID   | ITEM      | CATEGORY   |
---------------------------------
| 1    | COOKIES   | 1          |
| 2    | CAKE      | 1          |
| 3    | WATER     | 2          |
| 4    | PEANUTS   | 1          |
| 5    | PEPSI     | 2          |
```

Plus a categories table

```
--------------------
| ID   | ITEM      | 
--------------------
| 1    | FOOD  
| 2    | DRINK
```

AND query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE category=1;   (or 2)
```

Comment: Please, remove quotes for int values!

Comment: both. more efficiently because you can run complexe queries (if you need) it's a relationship database. It's better to run queries on int or date fields not on text or varchar fields. Are several reasons..

Comment: not the most flexible approach because this way you cannot have multiple categories for a single item; something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/48324559/191246 would be a more standard approach

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about normalization forms? You have duplicate data in your table. It more beautiful to create 2 tables: `item`, `category`.

item: (id, item, category_id)
category: (id, name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` instead of `text`