# An item with multiple categories in DB

Tags: database, database-design, relationship

I have a `contacts` table and a `contact_category` table. I am trying to reflect in table that one contact can belong to several categories.

Is there any recommended design pattern for implementing this? What comes to my mind is just creating a string in an additional field for every contact and concat the categories this contact belongs to.

For ex.:
`"cat1,cat3"` would mean that a contact belongs to `cat1` and `cat3`

But, isn't there any proper way of designing this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks for the advice, so it will be sort of many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Yeah, it's a many-to-many relationship. Many contacts per category, many categories per contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, a comma-delimited text field with multiple values is a bad idea in database design, in my rarely-humble opinion.

I'd recommend something like this (I code in SQL Server, so that's what my syntax will look like):

```
Contact
    ID    -- primary key
    -- other contact fields
Category
    ID    -- primary key
    -- other category fields

Contact_Category
    Contact_ID    -- foreign key to Contact
    Category_ID   -- foreign key to Category
```

The above allows you to associate a contact to multiple categories and a category to multiple contacts.  Let me know if you have any questions.